# How to control tabpage using listview or tree view

Tags: c#, listview

In many programs, such as PuTTY, uBittorrent, notepad++ and WinSCP, they use some kind of listview or treeview to organize the preference form, just like images shown below:
[image]
[image]
So what I would like to ask is that: in C# is there any native way to organize winform controls in this layout? What I have figured out is to load the right-hand side controls in a panel manually when user clicks the listview item on left side.
But is there any better solution which is directly supported by C#?

Thanks~

Comment: The recommended way is to compose serveral UserControls and show/hide one of them upon selecting the treeviewnode. - But of course you could simply use a Tab controls and align the tabs to the left. No nesting though..

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways this can be achieved. First to get the layout, I would use a table layout panel as the top most level control in the form and set it to have 2 columns. The left column will be the list view and the right column will show the associated page with the currently selected list view item.

I would create a simple model for each possible list view item something like

```
public class PageViewItemModel()
{
    public string ItemDescription { get; }

    public UserControl CustomUserControlForViewItem { get; }

    public PageViewItemModel()
    {
        // Initialize the associated custom user control here
        CustomUserControlForViewItem = new YourCustomUserControlClass();

        // Set the display name for the list view
        ItemDescription = MyListViewItemName;
    }
}
```

Of course you can create a generic class and use constructor parameters to do all this instead of creating a model for each possible item in the list view. But after you have your ListViewItemModel objects you can add them to your list view and set the DisplayName property to "ItemDescription" so it shows that value in the ListView.

Then create an event handler in the parent form that handles the SelectedIndexChanged event of the ListView which adds the associated custom user control to the right column of the TableLayOutPanel

```
public void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedIndex = myListView.SelectedIndex;

    PageViewItemModel model = myListView.Items[selectedIndex];

    myTableLayOutPanel.Controls.Add(model, 0, 1);
}
```

That's the gist of it.